# Android device not accessing web service on local WIFI

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, web-services, iis

I have made an asp web service and I am accessing it from my android application through ksoap2 library. I have successfully accessed the service from emulator by 10.0.2.2:9000/Service1.asmx.

---

Now I am trying to access it from my android device but I am not able to access it.
I have already hosted the service on IIS and now I can access it from emulator by 192.168.xx.xxx/Service1.asmx.

---

The problem is still the same  Can't see any result in my android app on device that is connected to the same LAN through WIFI, although I can see my web service through mobile browser now. In addition to that I have edited the web.config file to allow all systems on LAN to invoke my web service methods.

I just checked the error. Error toast is showing java io.IOException on device still runs without any error on emulator

Comment: have u added the permission for using internet in your manifest file.`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Obviously, thats why I am able to access it from emulator

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check whether 192.168.xx.xxx/Service1.asmx. is reachable via android mobile browser. I doubt that your device could be in some other ip group.